# How can I "refresh" the fragments in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am having an issue here that is driving me nuts. What I have is the following:

FragmentActivity1 holds the viewPager. It instantiates the FragmentAdapter and two fragments and attach them to the ViewPager.

Fragment1 has only one button. When user clicks this button, I create one Intent and invoke a FragmentActivty. This fragmentActivity contains a form, which the user fills in and press OK. When he does that, I persist the data in the DB of the app.

Fragment2 is a ListFragment, and lists all the data that was inserted previously by the user.

By the time user completes the form and presses OK, I persist the data, like I said and finish() the activity, returning to Fragment1. WHen I swype to Fragment2, the data is not there. I need then to swype to Frag1 and then back to Frag2. Only then I can see the problem.

I have tried setting listeners between activities and fragments but, still, cant make this work.

Have anyone seen? I am willing to share my small project as well, so you guys can take a look.

Thanks,
Felipe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually fill my ListView in onResume() in the ListFragment. When I'm done adding new stuff to the list (In a seperate FragmentActivity, just like you), the ListView automatically gets refreshed, because onResume() gets called ;)

Another approach is using onActivityResult(), then you can update list only when something new is added or something is removed

Comment: Let me try that. Will get back to you soon :-)

Comment: Jesus Christ, it actually works! It sucks not to know properly the Fragment's lifecyle! Been battling on that for 2 days now.
Ole, thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: To Felipe: which did you use, onResume() or onActivityResult()?